# How to prevent Swift Propertyobservers being called when changing variables within the observed object

Tags: ios, swift, property-observer

While testing I found this weird behavior:

```
var viewModel: ViewModel? {
    didSet {
        viewModel.delegate = self
    }
}

view.viewModel?.delegate = MockDelegate
```

This code will always result in the `viewModel.delegate` being the view.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Fistly check if viewModel is set. `view.viewModel = model` will set delegate as `ViewModel` `model` object.
Then `view.viewModel!.delegate = MockDelegate` will override the delegate object.

```
var viewModel: ViewModel? {
    didSet {
        viewModel.delegate = self // this is the issue.
    }
}

view.viewModel = model
// this line should override the delegate instance from self to `MockDelegate`
view.viewModel!.delegate = MockDelegate
```

Comment: That's the weird thing about it. It does override to MockDelegate and then the didSet kicks in and sets it to self again.

Comment: check `view.viewModel =` in your code. set the breakpoint on didSet, and check who is calling this line.

Comment: it's being called from the view.viewmodel?.delegate line. I've solved it with a check for nil, but am not happy with it. Don't know if this is intended behavior by Swift or not.